# Get innerWidth() equivalent without jQuery

Tags: javascript

I'm currently working on eliminating jQuery from some code that I've written, and I've got a portion of code in which I was computing both the inner and outer widths of some `span` elements. It seems like `.getBoundingClientRect()` works fine for getting the outer width of an element, but I'm a bit stuck on getting the inner width. (i.e. the width of the element sans padding and borders.)

I'm using d3 to create my spans, and I need to compute their inner widths so that I can effectively set the widths of some other elements in order to get them to line up. Is there a good way of getting inner width for a div without manually checking and subtracting the various .css properties that could affect it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not sure how stable this is, but the method that seems to be working is using `window.getComputedStyle(element).width`.

This gives the computed style as "95px", where 95 is the inner width (in pixels). I'm using `parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(element).width)` to get the inner width of the element as a number.

Comment: Please note that the value returned by this also depends on the box-sizing css property.

Comment: Specifically, this solution does not work if the web page sets `box-sizing: border-box` on all elements, which is probably common nowadays.

Answer (score 2):

Taken from jQuery:

```
Math.max(element.scrollWidth, element.offsetWidth, element.clientWidth)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try `.offsetWidth`. Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6vY9j/).

Comment: This seems to give the same result as `.getBoundingClientWidth()` (i.e. includes padding and borders).

Answer (score 0):

```
function innerWidth(elem) {
    if (elem != null && elem === elem.window) { // window
        return elem.document.documentElement.clientWidth;
    } else if (elem.nodeType === 9) { // document
        const doc = elem.documentElement;

        return Math.max(
            elem.body[ "scrollWidth" ], doc[ "scrollWidth" ],
            elem.body[ "offsetWidth" ], doc[ "offsetWidth" ],
            doc[ "clientWidth" ]
        );
    }
    return window.getComputedStyle(elem).width;
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).