# Best practice for checking if a div is showing all of its content

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

I have a `div` with some dynamic content which is plain text. I have also applied `max-height` to it and thus, some of the content might not be displayed. What I want to check is if the whole content is displayed after rendering.

So, my question is:

Is it best practice to check if `offsetHeight < scrollHeight` to see if the whole content of the div is displayed regarding its height?

Comment: You can do it that way, yes.

Comment: @JorgeFuentesGonzález I know that it can be done in that way. However, is it best practice?

Comment: Is not a bad practice actually. Depends a lot on your app and how do you do things.

Comment: `innerHeight` can be better than `offsetHeight` because it includes paddings, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4814398/how-can-i-check-if-a-scrollbar-is-visible/9016183#9016183) in a terrible, terrible thread.

Comment: @GaloisGirl Could you answer the question so I can accept your answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JQuery's `innerHeight` can be better than `offsetHeight` because it includes paddings, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4814398/how-can-i-check-if-a-scrollbar-is-visible/9016183#9016183)

Here's how to get innerHeight without jQuery: [Get innerWidth() equivalent without jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20748355/get-innerwidth-equivalent-without-jquery)